70's/80's book about a woman who comes to be able to use a sunstone
This is a book I borrowed from the library when I was in junior/senior high.
The plot revolved around a young woman who could use something called a sunstone (not sure if it was one word or two) and is sorta' pathetic, but gets better as she goes. It takes place in space partly, as I remember her being on the bridge of a ship.
Any ideas? Thanks!
Note this is not about Stjepan Sejic's Sunstone series nor Sydney J. Van Scyoc's Sunstone Scrolls series.

Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember what kind of effect she was able to get by using the sunstone?  Was it a source of light, or energy, or a guide, or something else?

It was sort of a mystical power - energy rays or something that could be used to fight. It's been a long, long time.

Are you entirely sure it was a spaceship?  Sunstones were actual things, IIRC birefractive in a way that allowed the user to find the exact position of the sun on an overcast day.  They were thought by some to be used (again, IIRC) by Vikings and possibly other seafarers  before accurate compasses and clocks (and astrolabes) were popular.

Yes, I'm sure she was on a spaceship.
